# FluidSurvey API - CSV filter

Tags: c#, api, csv, survey

I'm working with the [fluidsurveys](https://fluidsurveys.com/) API.

I have a survey and now I'm going to get survey data in `.csv` format.

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/fluidsurveys/apiv3/responses.html#filtering-responses)

My requirement is I need to save this response as `.csv` file. Would it be possible to do this?

Here is a code snippet I use:

```
public void Read(String urlParameters)
{
            String _clientURL = _url + urlParameters;
            _client = new RestClient(_clientURL);
            var req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            req.AddParameter("Content-Type", "text/csv", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
            req.AddParameter("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_apikey+':'+_passWord)), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
            var response = _client.Execute(req);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `File.WriteAllText("SomePath...", response)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to modify your method to save the csv string to a file you can do as follows:

```
public void Read(string urlParameters, string path)
{
    string _clientURL = _url + urlParameters;
    _client = new RestClient(_clientURL);
    var req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    req.AddParameter("Content-Type", "text/csv", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
    req.AddParameter("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_apikey+':'+_passWord)), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
    var response = _client.Execute(req);
    File.WriteAllText(path, response.Content);
}
```

Comment: I can generate .csv file. but Its like text file. 

Sample code : 
File.WriteAllText(path, response);

If there any way to format it as .csv file

Comment: @Gayan J what format are you receiving the file in? Perhaps you mean the extension of the file you want to be .csv?

Comment: response is IRestResponse object. So I can get the content using response.Content. Its a String. If I write in to .csv file its in same cell.